# 3D view doesnt match 2D view

Tags: 3d, anylogic

I modeled my agent as a 3d object and inserted a DAE file. When I run the model, the 2D view doesnt match the 3D view. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

My 2D view below:
[image]

My 3D view:
[image]

Comment: this looks like a bug in AnyLogic...

Comment: I restarted anylogic and it worked fine...silly me